# How do I get a mp3 files info duration, title, image etc in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3

I understand how to get a mp3 files info in Java but I'd like to attempt to put less strain on the server by implementing it in javascript. I am new to javascript and don't understand the syntax well. I found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmediatags and It looks like what I need but I tried to implement it and it didn't work 
basically I have a form like so

```
<form action="jsmediatags.read(document.getElementById("audiofile"));">
    <input type="file" name="audio" accept="audio/*">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add music"/>
</form>
```

I would like for `jsmediatags.read()` to pull the necessary info from the file on submit then send it to the server. Am I implementing this API in the wrong way? Is there a way to do it without the API?

Comment: you are doing 2 mistakes or even more: quotes don't nest - mix single and double ones (action="blabla('bla')"), jsmediatags cannot read from user's hard drive (it's file:// protocol but it would be huge security issue if any script could check files on user's PC)

Comment: Also, that link you found runs in Node.js, not "plain" JS. It's not clear, but it looks like you want this in "plain, website js", correct? If that is the case, I do not think "browser" JavaScript can do this.

Comment: @pzmarzly it would not be any security issue to read the file when the user has already selected a file from the `input[type=file]` - Here you are capitabel of using browserify  or webpack to make it into client side code that can read a arraybuffer from the input field

Comment: once file is selected, you may [check its size](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/08/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-1/) or [read the file to variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (getting info from it is going to be troublesome). Best way is to upload the file and use  server-side scripts imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsmediatags already has this browser part covered in the [readme](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags#browser)

```js
// From File
$inputTypeFile.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  jsmediatags.read(file, {
    onSuccess: function(tag) {
      console.log(tag);
      // use ajax to upload tag info, or create some new form elements
    },
    onError: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });              
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/aadsm/jsmediatags/master/dist/jsmediatags.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input id="$inputTypeFile" type="file" name="audio" accept="audio/*">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add music"/>
</form>
```

Comment: cant seem to get the duration of the file which is what i need the most

Comment: Try playing the audio file in a audio tag to find out what length it is

Comment: Using jsmediatags I've been able to get the duration in seconds from the TLE/TLEN tags (TLEN in id3v2.3, TLE in id3v2.2). Look up TLEN on http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0